# Is getNumPartitions an RDD action or transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Is RDD's `getNumPartitions` a transformation or an action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Is it an action?

**NO**, If you do `getNumPartition()` on any RDD, It just fetches the meta(`partitions.length`) of an RDD and no tasks will be submitted.

## Is it a transformation?

My understanding about transformation is ***"It should return an RDD when that function applied on RDD"***. But `getNumPartition()` return integer.

Check the definition of function in RDD.scala

```
  @Since("1.6.0")
  final def getNumPartitions: Int = partitions.length
```

Comment: :Thanks for the info. Doubt came from here https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/10/using-pyspark-to-perform-transformations-and-actions-on-rdd/ . They have mentioned getNumPartition as an Action.